# systemd: start openvpn.service after time has synced

Tags: systemd, real-time

I use systemd-timesyncd to sync the time on my system. It doesn't have a battery to save the RTC. When I connect it to the internet it takes about 30 seconds to sync the time. I would like to reduce the syncing time and looked into documentation of timesyncd and timesyncd.conf but haven't found any way to reduce it. I tried a script in /etc/network/if-up.d to restart timesyncd, but it didn't help.

I already thought about installing ntpd. I would prefer a way with timesyncd.

I'm running raspbian Jessie with systemd 215.

Thanks for your help
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Use ntpdate to set the time on demand.

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```